# App stops unexpectedly when applying a custom theme

Tags: android, themes

I am working a project out of a book on Android Programming.  It works fine when I run the first version.  However, the book then goes into applying styles to the list items, and the program is stopped when I look at the emulator.  It involves a class that extends AppCompatTextView that redraws each list item as a post it note.

Here is the MainActiviy code.

```
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
    final ImageButton myAddButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myAddButton);
    final ImageButton myDelButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myDelButton);
    final ImageButton myCanButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myCanButton);
    final ArrayList<String> toDoItems = new ArrayList<String>();


    int resId = R.layout.activity_main;

    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, resId, toDoItems);

    myEditText.setText("");
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            boolean result = getItemRecord(myListView, position);
            if (result)
                myListView.removeViewAt(position);
        }
    });

    myAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toDoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myEditText.setText("");
        }
    });
}
```

The lines with bullets are the only two lines that have changed.  They involve the use of the new class.  When I change them back to using activity_main the program works fine.

Here is the code for TodoListItemView

```
    public class TodoListItemView extends AppCompatTextView {
public TodoListItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int ds) 
{
    super(context, attributeSet, ds);
    init();
}

public TodoListItemView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public TodoListItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    init();
}

private Paint marginPaint;
private Paint linePaint;
private int paperColor;
private float margin;

private void init() {
    Resources myResources = getResources();
    Context context = getContext();

    marginPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


   marginPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,
   R.color.notepad_margin));

    linePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


  linePaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,
   R.color.notepad_lines));



  paperColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.notepad_paper);

    margin = myResources.getDimension(R.dimen.notepad_margin);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(paperColor);

    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getMeasuredHeight(), 0, linePaint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), linePaint);

    canvas.drawLine(margin, 0, margin, getMeasuredHeight(), marginPaint);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(margin, 0);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
}
```

I have a feeling it has to do with the getColor method in the lines with bullets.  The book uses the deprecated version, getColor(int), so I replaced it with ContextCompat.  The code builds but the app stops shortly after being fed to the emulator.

Here is the styles.xml

```
    <resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="ToDoTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

The lines with the asterisks (supposed to be bolded) define the custom theme

As always, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: post log buddy .

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

This is happening because you are setting the resource for ArrayAdapter to R.layout.activity_main, which is a LinearLayout. To populate the ListView with your TodoListItemView you have to simply make a layout file that holds the TodoListItemView. For example:

todo_list_item_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.test.TodoListItemView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And in your onCreate method:

```
int resId = R.layout.todo_list_item_view;
```

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: I am able to enter a value in the EditText, but when I hit the add button, it says the app has stopped.  I ran the debugger, and it is pointing at toDo_items.add statement in the click event. I'm not sure why it does this, as when I switch back to the old example, the app runs fine.

Comment: I ran the debugger on the app, and just as soon as hit the step into button it throws an exception in the EditText class and says the following at the top of the debugger 
 Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 52.0 (Java 8)
Sources for 'Android API Platform" not found.                                                      I checked my installed SDKs and the entry for Android 8 (26.0) says its partially installed